# PHP Compare two strings and display the difference while preserving their original character positions

Tags: php

For this I have been trying things myself and trying to find answers online for a while now. What I would like to achieve, is to compare two strings and display the difference in characters as an integer, whilst preserving the character positions. Basically, I have a question and answer app, and I need to compare the correct answer to the given answer. So, for example:

```
$correct = 'Monday';
$answer =  'Manday';
```

In the above example there is only one error made, so when comparing the `$correct` and `$answer` strings, I need to display "1".

I tried using `strcmp`, but that is not giving me the correct results. For the above example, doing `strcmp($original, $answer)` would give me this result: 3584.

Also when using `similar_text` I do not get the results I need. Example, when using `similar_text($original,$answer)`, while using the above `Monday` and `Manday` example, it gives an expected result of 5 characters that are similar, out of 6. But when I do the following, it still gives me 1 as a result, while it should be 0 (for my case):

```
similar_text("Hello", "World") // The "o" is matched, but it is in the wrong position
```

So, in short, what I need to achieve is this. I have a correct answer, and a user input given answer. I want to compare the user given answer against the original correct answer. And how do I want to compare them? I want to compare each character position from both strings, and for all characters that are incorrect, I want to return the total wrong characters as an integer.

Some more examples:

```
$str1 = 'Monday';
$str2 = 'Mondayy';
```

The above should return '1', because the second string has an extra character. So 1 error in total.

```
$str1 = 'Monday';
$str2 = 'Manday';
```

The above should return '1', because the second string has a one wrong character. So 1 error in total.

```
$str1 = 'Hello';
$str2 = 'World';
```

The above should return '5', because the second string does not match any of the first string's characters in their position. So 5 errors in total.

Comment: The value returned by [`strcmp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp) does not have any meaning. Only its sign is important.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into these methods a bit more to try and understand them better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `levenshtein()` instead of `similar_text()`

`similar_text()` just calculates the longest matching substring.  `levenshtein()` calculates how many characters have to be replaced to match the answer.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: I think that is exactly what I was looking for, nice that I overlooked this... Spent almost 30 minutes writing the question lol, should have found this ^^ Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't imagine "levenshtein" matches a lot of search terms, so it's understandable you didn't find it.  If this is the correct answer, please mark it as such.

Comment: I ofcourse will, Stackoverflow is telling me to wait 5 minutes :-)) And PS. I did find `levenshtein` somewhere before but I think I simply discarded it too fast.. Oh well, you helped me a bunch :)